# 2010 Volvo S80 - Cabin HVAC system schematics

Tags: ac, hvac, smell, diagram

Something in my sedan's cabin air system smells bad (organic bad, not mechanical bad), even after changing the cabin air filter.

I have a bore scope, vacuum, compressor, and hoses sufficient that I think I could find and clean out the source.  ***But* I have no idea what the layout of the system is and how it is configured in each mode** – i.e., what position each damper would be in, what dimensions I'm likely to encounter as I snake through the ducts, and where each of the HVAC components sit.  I'm not even sure where *all* of the intakes and outlets are.  (I also understand that just opening the entire system is a four-figure project.  Given the tools I have available that's probably unnecessary.)

**Where can I find a detailed schematic of the HVAC system for a late-model sedan?**

And are they generally similar enough between makes and models that one example would be enough to give me an idea of where components, dampers, and intakes are?

Or do they vary significantly enough that I would need a model-specific drawing?

Comment: We could do a lot better helping you if we knew what the year/make/model of the vehicle you are talking about .

Comment: Right now it's a 2010 Volvo S80, but I would appreciate answers for the question as posed (out of general interest and applicability).

Comment: The problem is, every manufacturer is going to design their vehicle differently and it's also going to be different between models and maybe even options on models might be different (i.e.: think about automatic HVAC versus manual HVAC controls). Because of this, there isn't going to be a right answer. Narrowing it down to a single model might allow us to provide you assistance.

Comment: @Paulster2 - that sounds like half of the answer right there.  E.g., there are some mechanics that are virtually identical to all modern sedans, like suspension components, brakes, engine cooling.  And there are some -- e.g., (I imagine) ECU and electric -- that vary so much even between trims that you need a trim-specific diagram.  The question is to what degree that is true of HVAC? The second half of the question would be: (a) *do such detailed schematics exist?* and (b) *where can one find them, or the next-best thing for the layout and function details I'm looking for?*

Comment: E.g., HVAC *features* might be quite variable, but whether a car has manual or automatic HVAC aren't all the dampers and other components going to be in the same place, and the ducting identical?  And if we're talking about the sedan layout I would be a little surprised to see that much variability between manufacturers, since all of the other common systems wouldn't leave much room for variation for ducts and component placement.  E.g., I've always found the cabin air filter tucked behind the glove box, center and side console outlets, windshield outlet, etc.

Comment: It's going to be different, and can be quite different between makes/models. And no, with different versions (automatic v. manual) the innards can be quite different as well. Think about a manual system using wires directly from the dials, and then with automatic you'd have vacuum actuated systems. The automatic ones can be quite a bit more complicated. That's just one example, there can be other differences as well. As far as the cabin air filter, they are usually on the passenger side of the car, but you can find them accessed under the glove box or from the engine compartment as well.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Fair enough, and all part of a valid answer.  Do you know whether schematics exist and where/how one can find or obtain them?  If it varies, let's find the 2010 Volvo S80.

Comment: The only place I could think of would be in a service manual if at all. Those can sometimes be found on eBay, but the dealership will have one ... and they don't usually lend them out (for some reason ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my A/C blow foul smelling air when it first turns on?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/116/why-does-my-a-c-blow-foul-smelling-air-when-it-first-turns-on)