# Why does my automobile air conditioning stink when I turn it on

Tags: ac, cooling-system

I read all over that the problem is mildew or antifreeze, but why doesnt it stink when I'm just blowing fresh air and the compressor isn't on? Seems to me that if it's the air ducts, for lack of a better term, it would always stink. My Jeep always stank when I got it, and I dried that out. My Camaro only stinks when I run the a/c.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/116/4152

Comment: Because the evaporator needs cleaning and only smells when wet...